# How can multiple web devs use git to work on one page simultaneously?

Tags: git, web, workflow, file-structure

We're looking into using git for a new system we're designing.

We currently have a production machine and a dev machine.
We use svn to keep production updated with our dev commits.

The dev machine has a complete copy of our codebase for each developer (just 2 of us currently).

Here's the file structure:

```
html/
  dev_timmy/
    stuff/
      thing1.php
      thing2.php
  dev_johnny/
    stuff/
      thing1.php
      thing2.php
```

If we were both working on thing1.php, I would make changes to the file in my directory, and he'd make changes to it in his. To test our changes, we simply include our dev directory in the url.

```
http://ourwebsite.com/dev_timmy/stuff/thing1.php
http://ourwebsite.com/dev_johnny/stuff/thing1.php
```

I'm sure having copies of code isn't the best solution.

But **how can we view our own changes on the internet**?
How can we make dev_timmy-based urls resolve to the version of the page that Timmy is working on?

Comment: You need to google for deployment solutions.  You'd have a server side hook that copies your files out to a location on your web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about git to help with this kind of thing: Files have to be on disk somewhere so they can be dished out by a web server.

This question basically boils down to workflow. If you want to be able to look at the code you're working on independent of the code your coworker is working on the general solution is to have multiple sites (either separate web servers or just different virtual hosts behind a server) setup with different URLs. For example at our company we each have our own dev vm, and our own `username.company.com` URL that we can use to refer to code hosted on our VM.

Generally people have their git repository as the document root (or virtual host root) for their web server. They edit and test on this, committing locally as they go.

When we're done with our development we merge to a central repository, and there's a web server in test that we can go to which shows what's currently merged for testing. Once that's been accepted it's merged to master and pushed to production.

Answer (score -1):

> But how can we view our own changes on the internet?

First of all you have to upload it to the internet of course.
You will need some place to store your code (bitbucket, gthub etc).

Those cloud services has a web interface to view your changes and all your history as well.

---

> How can we make dev_timmy-based urls resolve to the version of the page that Timmy is working on?

Using git you can use branches. Each one of you will have its own branch which will allow you 2 to work on the same code at the same time and update your local code whenever you want.

This is what branches are.

---

Another solution might be to use the same project as submodule or using workdir which will allow you to have the same code under different folders

Comment: I understand what a branch is. How can I tell my browser I want to look at timmy's branch (version of a certain page)?

Comment: Your browser has no knowledge of your git code, you can use the same url but checking out different branch when needed can display the different content

Comment: Added submodule and workdir as another options for you.

Comment: What if we're both working on the same page at the same time? Wouldn't we both need our respective branch to be the one checked out?

Comment: Nope, each one can work on his branch and once your work is done merge it back to the master.